# In Typescript, what should the return type be for a component returning MUI TableContainer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

My component is returning a MUI `Table`, wrapped inside `TableContainer`

```
const DataReleaseChart = (): React.FC<?> => {
  return (
    <TableContainer
      sx={{
        display: 'grid',
        rowGap: 7,
      }}
    >
      <Table>{chartRenderer(preCloseRowData)}</Table>
      <Table>{chartRenderer(closedRowData)}</Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
};

export default DataReleaseChart;
```

What should be the returned Type?

I have tried `ReactElement[]` but it gives the error of

```
Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.ts(2740)
```

I have also tried `React.FC` but got this

```
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.
  Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(props: { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any>'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: React.FC is not a return type of a function, its the type of FunctionComponent. So you should type it as `const DataReleaseChart: React.FC = () => {...` And since your function component doesn't have the props of TableContainer, you shouldn't explicitly type it as an TableContainer

Comment: @UgurEren got it. I placed the React.FC as a return type, which was wrong. So in this case, the return type is void? or is it okay to leave as is? Not seeing any TS errors.

Comment: No, FC is a function type, so it sets the return type to ReactElement automatically

Comment: @UgurEren Ah ha, I see. Appreciate it greatly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use ReactNode and make sure when  declare function then you have to put :FC **

```
import React, { FC, ReactNode } from "react";   
    
 const DataReleaseChart:FC<ReactNode> = () => {
  return (
    <TableContainer
      sx={{
        display: 'grid',
        rowGap: 7,
      }}
    >
      <Table>{chartRenderer(preCloseRowData)}</Table>
      <Table>{chartRenderer(closedRowData)}</Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
};

export default DataReleaseChart;
```

Comment: Thank you, so no need to specify the type for the return type? Like after the ' = (): someReturnType => ' . No need to write anything for the someReturnType?

Comment: No, you do not need to write some return type.

Comment: Because Typescript is aware that the Functional Component will return JSX . but if you like to put  :JSX.Element  in return type without React.FC it will work .Just remember you have to put :FC after function declared .